# Using Epplus to read spreadsheet and determine all the cell's style, including conditionally format

Tags: conditional-formatting, epplus

I am using Epplus (C#.net) to read the values and the styling of cells(background and font color) in a spreadsheet, that is protected and locked.

Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb; Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Theme and Style.Font.Color.Rgb; Style.Font.Color 
work correctly in most of the cells. I am running into a problem with cells that are using the conditional format 'Format only unique or duplicate values'. Background and Font colors are being returned from Epplus as null.

Here is the code to get the background/font color from a particular cell

```
    private ExcelStyleLoad GetStyleInfo(ExcelRange currentCell)
    {
        ExcelStyleLoad retval = new ExcelStyleLoad();
        //background
        retval.BackgroundColor = currentCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb;
        retval.BackgroundTheme = currentCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Theme;

        //font
        retval.FontColor = currentCell.Style.Font.Color.Rgb;
        retval.FontTheme = currentCell.Style.Font.Color.Theme;

        //other
        retval.isBold = currentCell.Style.Font.Bold;
        retval.isUnderline = currentCell.Style.Font.UnderLine;
        retval.isItalics = currentCell.Style.Font.Italic;

        retval.FullAddress = currentCell.FullAddress;
        return retval;
    }
```

I have also tried to use  currentCell.ConditionalFormatting.AddDuplicateValues() to determine the background/font color and have had no success.

Any suggestions how I can get the background/font color of the cells that are using the ConditionalFormatting?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, cells with conditional formatting do not (necessarily) have a backgroundcolor, they just have the conditional formatting rule. The background colour is infered from the value and the rule when the sheet is being displayed.

This meets your observation.

So you will have to look for conditional formatting in the cells and calculate the colour values yourself when reading the formatting. That's little hope in your case where the sheet is protected and locked.

Anyway, you should be able to determine unique / duplicate cells even in protected and locked sheets. Good luck!